# How to include extra ticks in pgfplots without them appearing in bold face?

Tags: pgfplots

In order to include a cross through the origin in my plot, I write the following under `\begin{axis}`:

```
extra x ticks={0},
extra y ticks={0},
extra tick style={grid=major},
```

However, the 0s appear in bold face in my plot. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Can you please include a simple example? Make sure that it is not printed twice that might create an illusion.

Comment: Your code-snippet doesn't demonstrate the problem- please make a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: For getting zero lines in your plot, take a look at [How can I add a zero line to a plot?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55718/how-can-i-add-a-zero-line-to-a-plot)

Comment: I just noticed that you seem to be using Joseph Wright's solution from the question I linked to. You forgot to also use the option `extra y tick labels=,`, which switches off the labels for the extra ticks.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that Joseph Wright's example was similar, but didn't notice the line turning off the extra tick labels (I also didn't understand that that was the reason for the boldface-looking 0s). Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're printing the labels twice, once with the regular ticks, once with the `extra x ticks` and `extra y ticks`, which looks as if they're printed bold. You'll need to switch the extra labels off, by using `extra y tick labels={}` and `extra x tick labels={}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    extra x ticks={0}, extra x tick labels={},
    extra y ticks={0}, extra y tick labels={},
    extra tick style={grid=major},
]
\addplot{rand};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```