# Set x tick label position to bottom of the axis

Tags: pgfplots

I have finally managed to center my data with `axis x line*=center`, but I haven't found a way to get my `x tick labels` at the bottom of the figure. I have already drawn some major grid lines and now I want my tick labels to be at the bottom of my figure.

I have tried to use `at={()}`, but that did not seem to work.

[image: The tick labels are now on the axis.]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotstableread{data/multicontrol.dat}\datatable

    \begin{axis}[ybar=0,
    bar width={0.2cm},
    xticklabels from table={\datatable}{variable},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={
        rotate=60,anchor=east},
    yticklabels={X,Very Bad, Bad, Neutral, Good, Very Good},
    xmajorgrids,
    ymin=-2,
    ymax=2,
    axis x line*=middle,
    axis y line*=left,
    enlarge x limits,
    y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1-3}}
    ]

    \addplot table[x=X,y=old] {\datatable};
    \addlegendentry{Joystick}
    \addplot table[x=X,y=new] {\datatable};
    \addlegendentry{Mouse}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Example data:

```
X   variable                    old         new
1   {Know where I am}           2.375       4
2   {Know what I see}           3.375       4.375
3   {See target directly}       2.428571429 4.5
4   {Know origin}               3.875       4.285714286
5   {Direct Adjustment (inv)}   2.625       3.75
6   {Screen position}           3.25        4.125
7   {Expectation}               2.25        2.375
8   {Get lost (inv)}            2.714285714 3.5
9   {Number dependent (inv)}    2           4
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest thing to do here is to use `axis x line*=left` (instead of middle), which will place the axis line and the labels at the bottom of the plot, and to "fake" the zero line using one of the approaches from [How can I add a zero line to a plot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55718/how-can-i-add-a-zero-line-to-a-plot).

[image]

---

For this graph, may I suggest flipping the axes around? That would make it much easier to read the labels, since you can do without the rotation:

[image]

---

*Code for first solution*

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotstableread{
X   variable                    old         new
1   {Know where I am}           2.375       4
2   {Know what I see}           3.375       4.375
3   {See target directly}       2.428571429 4.5
4   {Know origin}               3.875       4.285714286
5   {Direct Adjustment (inv)}   2.625       3.75
6   {Screen position}           3.25        4.125
7   {Expectation}               2.25        2.375
8   {Get lost (inv)}            2.714285714 3.5
9   {Number dependent (inv)}    2           4
}\datatable

    \begin{axis}[ybar=0,
    bar width={0.2cm},
    xticklabels from table={\datatable}{variable},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={
        rotate=60,anchor=east},
    yticklabels={X,Very Bad, Bad, Neutral, Good, Very Good},
    xmajorgrids,
    ymin=-2,
    ymax=2,
    axis x line*=left,
    axis y line*=left,
    enlarge x limits,
    y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1-3}},
    after end axis/.code={\draw ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,0});}
    ]

    \addplot table[x=X,y=old] {\datatable};
    \addlegendentry{Joystick}
    \addplot table[x=X,y=new] {\datatable};
    \addlegendentry{Mouse}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

*Code for second solution*

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotstableread{
X   variable                    old         new
1   {Know where I am}           2.375       4
2   {Know what I see}           3.375       4.375
3   {See target directly}       2.428571429 4.5
4   {Know origin}               3.875       4.285714286
5   {Direct Adjustment (inv)}   2.625       3.75
6   {Screen position}           3.25        4.125
7   {Expectation}               2.25        2.375
8   {Get lost (inv)}            2.714285714 3.5
9   {Number dependent (inv)}    2           4
}\datatable

    \begin{axis}[xbar=0,
    bar width={0.2cm},
    yticklabels from table={\datatable}{variable},
    ytick=data,
    xticklabels={X,Very Bad, Bad, Neutral, Good, Very Good},
    xmajorgrids,
    xmin=-2,
    xmax=2,
    axis x line*=left,
    axis y line*=left,
    enlarge x limits,
    x filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1-3}},
    after end axis/.code={\draw ({rel axis cs:0,0}-|{axis cs:0,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,1}-|{axis cs:0,0});},
    legend style={at={(1,0.9)}}
    ]

    \addplot table[y=X,x=old] {\datatable};
    \addlegendentry{Joystick}
    \addplot table[y=X,x=new] {\datatable};
    \addlegendentry{Mouse}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would like to know if I'm doing a good job inserting `yticklabels={X,Very Bad, Bad, Neutral, Good, Very Good}`. It seems a little hacky with the `X` in front, but that was the only way to get it working somehow.

Comment: @Marnix: You can avoid the dummy label by specifying the y tick positions: `ytick={-2,...,2},
    yticklabels={Very Bad, Bad, Neutral, Good, Very Good}`