# How to draw an additional line over an existing TikZ figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

```
\documentclass[border=5mm] {standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{ % Read the data into a table macro
Label   First   Second  Third
10      0.1     0.3     0.3
20      0.2     0.3     0.3
30      0.3     0.4     0.5
40      0.3     0.5     0.8
160     0.5     0.9     1.5
}\datatable

\begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked,   % Stacked horizontal bars
    xmin=0,         % Start x axis at 0
    ytick=data,     % Use as many tick labels as y coordinates
    yticklabels from table={\datatable}{Label}  % Get the labels from the Label column of the \datatable
]
\addplot [fill=yellow] table [x=First, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};    % Plot the "First" column against the data index
\addplot [fill=green!70!blue]table [x=Second, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\addplot [fill=red!80!yellow] table [x=Third, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now how do I draw a vertical black line parallel to the Y axis going through 1 on x axis?
And how do I put a label on this line?

Comment: You might use something like `\draw[dotted](axis description cs:0.3,0)--(axis description cs:0.3,1);` as per _4.8.1 Placement of Axis Descriptions_ in the manual. Fix the `0.3` to locate the line in the right position.

Comment: You have a couple of options, see [How can I add a zero line to a plot?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55718/how-can-i-add-a-zero-line-to-a-plot). All of the approaches there allow you to specify the value exactly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use Joseph's approach from [How can I add a zero line to a plot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55718/how-can-i-add-a-zero-line-to-a-plot): By setting `extra x ticks={1}`, you can define an additional tick that can be formatted differently from the others. By setting `extra x tick style={xmajorgrids=true}`, you can switch on the grid line for this tick, resulting in a vertical line:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm] {standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{ % Read the data into a table macro
Label   First   Second  Third
10      0.1     0.3     0.3
20      0.2     0.3     0.3
30      0.3     0.4     0.5
40      0.3     0.5     0.8
160     0.5     0.9     1.5
}\datatable

\begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked,   % Stacked horizontal bars
    xmin=0,         % Start x axis at 0
    ytick=data,     % Use as many tick labels as y coordinates
    yticklabels from table={\datatable}{Label},  % Get the labels from the Label column of the \datatable
    extra x ticks={1},  % Add an extra tick at position x=1
    extra x tick style={    % Set styles that only apply to the extra tick
            xticklabel pos=right,   % Put the label on the right ( = top) side of the plot
            xticklabels={Special!}, % Set the label text
            xmajorgrids=true            % Draw grid line
        }
]
\addplot [fill=yellow] table [x=First, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};    % Plot the "First" column against the data index
\addplot [fill=green!70!blue]table [x=Second, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\addplot [fill=red!80!yellow] table [x=Third, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks...how can I name the x axis as 'time in ms' and y axis as 'number of iterations'?

Comment: xlabel= 
        ylabel=