# draw grid in pgfplots when axis line=none

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to have a grid in the y axis although the axis y line is not drawn, either by setting `axis y line=none` or `hide y axis`. In the MWE below the horizontal line along y=0 is not drawn when I use the extra y ticks method described [in one of the answers here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55718/how-can-i-add-a-zero-line-to-a-plot). How could it work when the y axis is not displayed?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    extra y ticks       = 0,
    extra y tick style  = { grid = major },
    domain=0:360,
    hide y axis,
    ]
    \addplot {sin(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The key `hide y axis` completely disables all ticks and lines, `extra` or otherwise. Instead, you can stop the axis line from being drawn by setting

```
separate axis lines,
y axis line style= { draw opacity=0 }
```

The `separate axis lines` is necessary to be able to assign the line style only to the y axis, since usually the axes are drawn with a single path. Note that you have to use `draw opacity=0` to hide the y axis, the usual approach `draw=none` doesn't work here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    domain=0:360,
    ytick=0,
    separate axis lines,
    y axis line style= { draw opacity=0 },
    ymajorgrids,
    tick pos = left
    ]
    \addplot {sin(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

In case you want to do away with the tick mark and the tick label, the easiest thing might be to use one of the approaches from [How can I add a zero line to a plot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55718/how-can-i-add-a-zero-line-to-a-plot) to draw the zero line without the tick/grid mechanism.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    domain=0:360,
    hide y axis,
    before end axis/.code={
      \draw [/pgfplots/every axis grid] ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,0});
    },
    axis lines*=left
    ]
    \addplot {sin(x)};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! that works great except that I would like to remove the tick and ytick={} yticklabel=\empty does not do it,

Comment: @MigueldeVal-Borro: Yeah, to get rid of the tick mark you would have to set `major tick length=0pt`, but that would apply to the x axis as well. I've edited my answer to show a different approach.

Comment: Excellent! Since I am using the extra x ticks method for the x axis and would like to have the same style, is the default extra tick style `gray, very thin` or `gray, ultra thin` ?

Comment: @MigueldeVal-Borro: The default style is `thin,black!25`. You can also use the actual style that's used to draw the grid lines by adding `/pgfplots/every axis grid` to the `\draw` options.

Comment: With the release of PGFPlots v1.13 the bug has been fixed and now also `y axis line style={draw=none}` works fine.

Comment: @Jake I am sorry for asking this question here, but how can I remove a major or minor grid line at a specific x tick? For example, I need to remove the major grid line at `x=2000`.