# Custom colormap breaks colorbar: Cannot remove border and Mac Preview doesn't show colorbar

Tags: pgfplots, color

I have a custom colormap. And I have a plot with a colorbar.

**Without custom colormap:** No border around the colorbar, as intended. Looks perfectly fine in Mac Preview.

**With custom colormap:** Black border around the colorbar in TeX-studio preview. No colorbar, only black frame, in Mac Preview.

Here a MWE. Just uncomment the custom colorbar and hopefully you will get the same strange result as I do and know how to fix it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

%\pgfplotsset{colormap={blueColormap}{[2pt]%
%       color(0000pt)=(RoyalBlue!50!black);
%       color(1000pt)=(RoyalBlue!50!black);
%       color(1000pt)=(RoyalBlue!70!black);
%       color(2000pt)=(RoyalBlue!70!black);
%       color(2000pt)=(RoyalBlue!90!black);
%       color(3000pt)=(RoyalBlue!90!black);
%       color(3000pt)=(RoyalBlue!90!white);
%       color(4000pt)=(RoyalBlue!90!white);
%       color(4000pt)=(RoyalBlue!70!white);
%       color(5000pt)=(RoyalBlue!70!white);
%       color(5000pt)=(RoyalBlue!50!white);
%       color(6000pt)=(RoyalBlue!50!white);
%   }
%}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                colorbar,
                colorbar style={
                    ytick style={draw=none},
                    ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6},
                    yticklabels={0,1,2,3,4,5,6},
                    axis line style = { draw = none }
                },
                point meta min=0, 
                point meta max=6
            ]
            \foreach \n in {0,1,...,5}
                %{\edef\temp{\noexpand
                \addplot[ultra thick, smooth,mesh,point meta={\n+0.5},domain={0:1}] {x^\n}; %}\temp}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try all first with Acrobat Reader. Then it is very easy to dismiss the viewer issues.

Comment: "An error exists on this page..." says Acrobat DC.

Comment: And also shows only the empty black frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause is that your `colormap` definition is invalid and `pgfplots` failed to complain: the colormap contains multiple values for the same offset.

The problem can be reduced to the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{colormap={blueColormap}{%[2pt]%
       color(0000pt)=(RoyalBlue!50!black);
       color(1000pt)=(RoyalBlue!50!black);
       color(1000pt)=(RoyalBlue!70!black);
       color(2000pt)=(RoyalBlue!70!black);
       color(2000pt)=(RoyalBlue!90!black);
       color(3000pt)=(RoyalBlue!90!black);
       color(3000pt)=(RoyalBlue!90!white);
       color(4000pt)=(RoyalBlue!90!white);
       color(4000pt)=(RoyalBlue!70!white);
       color(5000pt)=(RoyalBlue!70!white);
       color(5000pt)=(RoyalBlue!50!white);
       color(6000pt)=(RoyalBlue!50!white);
   }
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                colorbar,
                point meta min=0, 
                point meta max=6
            ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This example shows fine in `evince` and `xpdf`, but Acrobat Reader shows a popup that the pdf is invalid.

The solution is to eliminate double offsets. The following works fine:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{colormap={blueColormap}{%[2pt]%
       color(0000pt)=(RoyalBlue!50!black);
       color(1000pt)=(RoyalBlue!50!black);
       %color(1000pt)=(RoyalBlue!70!black);
       color(2000pt)=(RoyalBlue!70!black);
       %color(2000pt)=(RoyalBlue!90!black);
       color(3000pt)=(RoyalBlue!90!black);
       %color(3000pt)=(RoyalBlue!90!white);
       color(4000pt)=(RoyalBlue!90!white);
       %color(4000pt)=(RoyalBlue!70!white);
       color(5000pt)=(RoyalBlue!70!white);
       %color(5000pt)=(RoyalBlue!50!white);
       color(6000pt)=(RoyalBlue!50!white);
   }
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                colorbar,
                point meta min=0, 
                point meta max=6
            ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or, in order to keep your "jumps":

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{colormap={blueColormap}{[2pt]%
       color(0000pt)=(RoyalBlue!50!black);
       color(1000pt)=(RoyalBlue!50!black);
       color(1002pt)=(RoyalBlue!70!black);
       color(2000pt)=(RoyalBlue!70!black);
       color(2002pt)=(RoyalBlue!90!black);
       color(3000pt)=(RoyalBlue!90!black);
       color(3002pt)=(RoyalBlue!90!white);
       color(4000pt)=(RoyalBlue!90!white);
       color(4002pt)=(RoyalBlue!70!white);
       color(5000pt)=(RoyalBlue!70!white);
       color(5002pt)=(RoyalBlue!50!white);
       color(6000pt)=(RoyalBlue!50!white);
   }
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                colorbar,
                point meta min=0, 
                point meta max=6
            ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that this last file takes a very long time since the colormap contains thousands of data points -- and since the involved colors are given in CMYK which requires extra effort (compare the warning stated by pgfplots).

My suggestions to overcome performance limitations are
* reduce the sampling density of the colormap (i.e. do not use `2pt` as mesh width on a scale of [0:6000], increase the mesh width considerably)
* redefine the input color as RGB color which simplifies the rendering of the color bar

---

*EDIT*

You also asked "why is there an unanticipated black frame, but only for my custom colormap?"

This is due to the fact that `blueColormap` is a CMYK colormap (because `RoyalBlue` is defined in CMYK). Pgfplots can handle CMYK shadings, but PGF cannot. In order to satisty this constraint, Pgfplots applies special steps for the `colorbar` which, unfortunately, cause `draw=none` to be ignored. I have just found and fixed this issue; it was present whenever an `\addplot3` statement occurred in an axis.

A simple workaround is to add `colormap default colorspace=rgb` *before* you define your custom colormap:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    colormap default colorspace=rgb,
    colormap={blueColormap}{
       color(0000pt)=(RoyalBlue!50!black);
       color(1000pt)=(RoyalBlue!50!black);
       color(2000pt)=(RoyalBlue!70!black);
       color(3000pt)=(RoyalBlue!90!black);
       color(4000pt)=(RoyalBlue!90!white);
       color(5000pt)=(RoyalBlue!70!white);
       color(6000pt)=(RoyalBlue!50!white);
   }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                colorbar,
                colorbar style={
                    axis line style={draw=none},
                },
                point meta min=0, 
                point meta max=6
            ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah ok, I kind of suspected something like that, but since I simply copied the colormap from an example here at teX.se, I assumed that it would work. Maybe I should add a comment to these answers linking to this question.

Comment: The black frame around the colorbar still remains, any ideas on that?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of that second sub-question. See my edit.

Comment: duplicate of that last issue: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126236/draw-grid-in-pgfplots-when-axis-line-none

Comment: However, if I use your workaround for the frame, the colors in the colorbar look completely different than what they looked before. Is there no chance to fix it using the dvipsnames colors?

Comment: hm, ok... you are right, the interpolation becomes different due to the color spaces. In this case, you can also resort to the workaround mentioned in the link above, i.e. to use `draw opacity=0` instead of `draw=none`. This will also work with CMYK

Comment: There is still an issue. As it turns out, my printer refuses to print any pdf file containing a plot with the above colorbar (using the print menu of the newest Adobe Reader).

Comment: Have you tried to reduce the number of samples _in the colormap_, i.e. to replace `[2pt]` by something bigger? That's the only thing that I could find when I tried to reproduce your issue locally: with `[2pt]`, I get an error if I print to a file. As soon as I have `[4pt]` (and valid input, of course!), it appeared to work. Note that `[2pt]` results in 3000 sample points which is way too much anyway.

Comment: Ok, with 4pt it works, at least with the Adobe Reader. What is the minimum number of sample points you would suggest to still have sharp and clean transitions when printing the document?

Comment: Well, the fact that it failed with `[2pt]` smells like a bug in pgfplots and I will track it. Aside of that, I believe that you can safely increase the mesh width considerably. Just use trial and error to get a good-looking result.