# pgfplots: Add main diagonal (identity line) without affecting the axis

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to add a main diagonal to a plot that does not affect the axis. The line should start and end at the axis or beyond them. Furthermore, I would like to avoid `xmin`and `xmax`, because I work with data tables. I tried relative coordinates `rel axis cs`, but this does not result in a main diagonal (slope 1 and offset 0). Here is a minimal working example to start with:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \pgfplotsset{width=0.9\columnwidth}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot coordinates {(0,0.1)(1,2)(2,3)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks similar: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55718/how-can-i-add-a-zero-line-to-a-plot. You can use `axiscs` in combination with `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}` and variants to produce the main diagonal. I believe this will only work if you draw the line after your plot your data.

Comment: By 'main diagonal', do you mean a line with slope 1 passing through the origin?

Comment: @sudosensei: It is similar, but I do not want to specify `xmin` and `xmax`, because my data comes from tables that can change. @Jack Yes, slope 1 and no offset.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the question. Apologies. I have deleted my answer. You are in good hands with Jake. He's helped me countless times so far. `:-)`

Comment: No problem. However, your answer gives me the correct hint to solve the problem, as you see in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for the hint to [percuss's excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55744/14200), [sudosensei](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/32206/sudosensei)! From his code I derived the following one:

```
\draw[red]
(axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}) -- 
(axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax});
```

This solves my problem:
[image]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \pgfplotsset{width=0.9\columnwidth}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot coordinates {(0,0.1)(1,2)(2,3)};
        \draw[red]
            (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}) -- 
            (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness: Use `\addlegendimage{line legend, red}\addlegendentry{Theory}` to add a legend to the red line.