# pgfplots - Zero lines draw over anything else, especially node/pins

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

For adding zero lines to every plot produced by pgfplots, I used the code provided by percusse [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55718/how-can-i-add-a-zero-line-to-a-plot). (A quick note after 2 replies were provided: this is a "global" solution. If one likes to add the zero lines to one plot only, see [esdd's reply](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183678/25683).)

The zero lines are the last item added to every axis environment so they'll get drawn over anything that was drawn before. This is a bit ugly in the case that a pin or node is next to/on the y-axis. Of course I can move some pins' positions by changing their parameters but all in all, some will have to stay near/on the y-axis so it isn't possible for all pins.

Is this possible to solve? Or would anyone have to offer some advice anyway?

### Picture of Problem

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\tikzset{
every pin/.style={
    draw=black,
    fill=white
},
every pin edge/.style={
    draw=black!60,
    fill=white,
    thick
},}

\pgfplotsset{
every axis/.append style={
%
xmajorgrids={true},
ymajorgrids={true},
xminorgrids={false},
yminorgrids={false},
%
after end axis/.code={
    %   \fill[red] (axis cs:0,0) circle(5pt);
    \draw[thin] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
    \draw[thin] (axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
},
},
every tick/.append style={
    black,
    thick
},
/pgf/number format/.cd,
use comma,
1000 sep={.},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot {rand};
    \filldraw (axis cs:0.9,0.9) circle [radius=1pt];
    \node[pin={[pin distance=0.3cm]180:{0.9} }] at (axis cs:0.9,0.9) {};
    \node[pin=0:{0.9}] at (axis cs:0.9,0.9) {};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move the drawing as being the first thing to be drawn via `execute at begin axis` key. Hence the only modification required is

```
execute at begin axis={%
    %   \fill[red] (axis cs:0,0) circle(5pt);
    \draw[thin] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
    \draw[thin] (axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
},
```

then you get,

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a suggestion using the special node `current axis` with the anchors `above origin`, `below origin`, `left of origin` and `right of origin`:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\tikzset{
  every pin/.style={draw=black,fill=white},
  every pin edge/.style={draw=black!60,fill=white,thick},
}

\pgfplotsset{
  every axis/.append style={
    xmajorgrids={true},
    ymajorgrids={true},
    xminorgrids={false},
    yminorgrids={false},
  },
  every tick/.append style={black,thick},
  /pgf/number format/.cd,
  use comma,
  1000 sep={.},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
% zero lines:
    \draw[thin] (current axis.above origin) -- (current axis.below origin);
    \draw[thin] (current axis.left of origin) -- (current axis.right of origin);
%
    \addplot {rand};
    \filldraw (axis cs:0.9,0.9) circle [radius=1pt];
    \node[pin={[pin distance=0.3cm]180:{0.9} }] at (axis cs:0.9,0.9) {};
    \node[pin=0:{0.9}] at (axis cs:0.9,0.9) {};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** Of course this node can also be used in `execute at begin axis`:

```
\pgfplotsset{
  every axis/.append style={
    xmajorgrids={true},
    ymajorgrids={true},
    xminorgrids={false},
    yminorgrids={false},clip=false,
  },
  execute at begin axis={%
    \draw[thin] (current axis.above origin) -- (current axis.below origin);
    \draw[thin] (current axis.left of origin) -- (current axis.right of origin);
  },
  every tick/.append style={black,thick},
  /pgf/number format/.cd,
  use comma,
  1000 sep={.},
}
```

Comment: Not what I was looking for at all and I already know about it, but definitely something others might find interesting! I linked your post in the op.

Comment: You can use this node also in `execute at begin axis`.