# Add a horizontal line to a PGFPlot and add it to the legend

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a PGF Plot with some computational results from a CSV file. At the time the CSV file was generated, there was a value that was not known. That value needs to be on the plot also, however.

What I have so far is:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [xlabel=Iteration, ylabel=Objective]
            \addplot [mark=none, blue] table [x=it, y=C, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
            \addlegendentry{Incumbent Solution}
            \addplot [mark=none, red] table [x=it, y=C*, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
            \addlegendentry{Best Solution}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Convergence of our simulated annealing algorithm}
    \label{fig_SA}
\end{figure}
```

which places two curves. Now I would like to add a straight line on the plot and an entry into the legend "Optimal Solution" corresponding to that straight line.

If it's easier, I can add this to the CSVs, but I'd prefer if I could just add it into my TeX code instead.

I saw [this similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55718/how-can-i-add-a-zero-line-to-a-plot) but I don't think any of the proposed solutions support adding the data series to the legend.

Comment: Any problem with `\addplot [mark=none, black] {0.5}; \addlegendentry{Constant Value}`?

Comment: I guess not. Except that I had only discovered PGFPlots about 20 minutes prior so did not know you could do that ;) Thanks!

Comment: @PaulGessler an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`pgfplots` will plot functions by default, and the simplest case of a function is a constant value, as you have requested. Simply add `\addplot[mark=none, black] {0.5};` (replace `0.5` with your constant value) and style to suit. The legend entry is added in the usual manner.

The default `domain` for a plotted function is [-5,5], which will change the view of your initial plot. I have restricted this by setting `xmin` and `xmax` limits in the options for the `axis` environment. I've also set `samples=2` to lighten the computation load slightly at the recommendation of Christian Feuersänger in the comments. The default is `samples=25`, but we only need 2 samples to adequately represent a constant.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
  xlabel=Iteration,
  ylabel=Objective,
  xmin=-0.1,xmax=1.1, % <-- added here to preserve view
]
  \addplot[mark=none, blue] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
  \addlegendentry{Incumbent Solution}
  \addplot[mark=none, red] coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
  \addlegendentry{Best Solution}
  \addplot[mark=none, black, samples=2] {0.5};
  \addlegendentry{Constant Value}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The default sample count is 25, so you may want to change it to `samples=2` for your constant.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger fixed; thanks! I suppose we ought to save a bit of bandwidth wherever possible. ;-)

Comment: @PaulGessler I just had a chance to try this out. It appears to just put a small dash at x=0 at my nominated y value; it doesn't draw a full line like in your example. I tried with and without the xmin/xmax. \addplot [mark=none, black] {390.588};

Comment: Not sure; my example works on my system. Have you checked that everything's up-to-date? If it is, and you're still not getting the output pictured, we need a complete MWE to diagnose (beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`).

Comment: @PaulGessler http://pastebin.com/CgwVPeRh produces https://i.imgur.com/W0dcaCL.png for me. I tried with the compat=1.10 and that made no difference.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, the default is `domain=-5:5`. If your data extend beyond this domain, and you want your constant line to do so as well, you need to adjust the `domain`. For your example, `domain=0:500` seems like it should be just about right. You can, of course, adjust this as needed.

Comment: This is why we ask for minimal self-contained examples; I had to make assumptions about your data because you did not provide a condensed version of your `data.csv` for us to work with.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! https://i.imgur.com/hy3J3Nl.png I totally missed your domain comment in the answer, even after you pointed it out. I had to ctrl+f for it before I noticed.

Comment: Great; I'm glad it's working now! :-)